# check if app can manage page

Tags: facebook, permissions

I have a problem here. I have three parameters which I want to check if they go along together:

- an app id
- an page id
- an impersonated app access token for manage_pages permission for the
  given page id.

What I want to do now is to check if the given app really can access and manage the given page with the given access token.
In detail - I want to check if the app could post on the pages wall in behalf of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access https://graph.facebook.com/pageID?fields=access_token&access_token=... and if it returns a valid result, that means you have proper manage_pages permission, which is the permission you need to post images as an admin of the page.

Comment: It's documented on the Facebook Permissions page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/